# Why Does Ejabberd Start Fail?

Tags: installation, ejabberd

I am trying to install `ejabberd 2.1.10-2` on my `Ubuntu 12.04.1` server. This is a fresh install, and ejabberd is never successfully installed.

### The Install

Every time, apt-get hangs on this:

```
Setting up ejabberd (2.1.10-2ubuntu1) ...
Generating SSL certificate /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem...

Creating config file /etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg with new version
Starting jabber server: ejabberd............................................................ failed.
```

The dots just go forever until it times out or I 'killall' `beam`, `beam.smp`, `epmd`, and `ejabberd` processes.  I've turned off all firewall restrictions.

Here's the output of `epmd -names` while the install is hung:

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name ejabberdctl at port 42108
name ejabberd at port 39621
```

And after it fails:

```
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name ejabberd at port 39621
```

At the same time (during and after), the output of both `netstat -atnp | grep 5222` and `netstat -atnp | grep 5280` is empty.

---

### The Crash File

A crash dump file is create at `/var/log/ejabber/erl_crash.dump`. The slogan (i.e. reason for the crash) is:

```
Slogan: Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,kernel,{shutdown,{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}})
```

---

### It's alive?

Whenever I try to relaunch ejabberd with `service ejabberd start`, the same thing happens - even if I've killed all processes before doing so.

However, when I killall the processes listed above again, and run `su - ejabberd -c /usr/sbin/ejabberd`, this is the output I get:

```
Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.8.5  (abort with ^G)
(ejabberd@ns1)1> 
=INFO REPORT==== 15-Oct-2012::12:26:13 ===
I(<0.478.0>:ejabberd_listener:166) : Reusing listening port for 5222

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Oct-2012::12:26:13 ===
I(<0.479.0>:ejabberd_listener:166) : Reusing listening port for 5269

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Oct-2012::12:26:13 ===
I(<0.480.0>:ejabberd_listener:166) : Reusing listening port for 5280

=INFO REPORT==== 15-Oct-2012::12:26:13 ===
I(<0.40.0>:ejabberd_app:72) : ejabberd 2.1.10 is started in the node ejabberd@ns1
```

Then, the server appears to be running. I get a login prompt when I access `http://mydomain.com:5280/admin/`. Of course I can't login unless I create an account.

At this time, the output of `netstat -atnp | grep 5222` and `netstat -atnp | grep 5280` is as follows:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19347/beam      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5280            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      19347/beam
```

---

### ejabberdctl

Even when it appears ejabberd is running, trying to do anything with ejabberdctl fails. For example: trying to register a user:

```
root@ns1:~# ejabberdctl register myusername mydomain.com mypassword
Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@ns1: nodedown
```

---

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. This happens on two different servers I have with identical software installed (really not much of anything). Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried either acquiring a binary/package from the developer web site or building from source?  Also, have you tested installing it in a VM (or actual install) of 12.10?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this problem one time when the daemon could not determine the ip address of the hostname I gave in the ejabber config file. My solution was to edit /etc/hosts file and make sure that there was a hostname entry for my public ip address and the domain I wanted ejabber to respond to.

```
0.0.0.0 hostname.domain.com hostname
1.1.1.1 ns1.yahoo.com ns1
```

Well, you get the picture. Hope that helps.

Comment: I checked, and I already have an entry in my /etc/hosts file with my domain name and public IP. However, I think you're on the right track with this. I just noticed the error message says "Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd@ns1". ns1 is the machine's name but it is not the domain name. Should that show the domain name there?

Comment: yeah for sure.. You should at least add ns1 to the hosts file as well. like 0.0.0.0 <FQDN> <hostname>

Comment: Holy... I don't even... Adding ns1 to my /etc/hosts file worked. Good grief.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it taken care of. Good luck and may the force be with you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is apparmor issue with no access from ejabberd socket (erlang sub-process of notify systemd) -> systemd WATCHDOG. Easiest is to disable apparmor profile with:

ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ejabberdctl /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ejabberdctl

for now.